# set default date using datepicker in jQuery and Razor (c#)

Tags: c#, razor, jquery-ui-datepicker

We have a common.js file which contains the commonly used client/jquery related functions and validations. This common.js is included in the _Layout.cshtml. In this common.js file we have datepicker code, to maintain uniformity across application,  as below,

```
function OsDatepicker(id, date, maxdt, dDate) {
    var ctrl = "#" + id;
    var d = new Date();

    var currYear = d.getFullYear();
    if (date == 0)
        var yrrange = (parseInt(currYear) - 4) + ":" + (parseInt(currYear) + 2);
    else
        var yrrange = (parseInt(currYear) - 70) + ":" + (currYear);

    $(ctrl).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        changeYear: true,
        autoSize: true,
        yearRange: yrrange,
        constrainInput: true,
        showOn: "both",
        buttonImage: '../../../Content/images/Calendar.png',
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        showanim: "slide",
        //defaultDate: dDate,  //not working  
        inline: true
    });

    if (maxdt == 0)
        $(ctrl).datepicker("option", "maxDate", "+0d");

    $(ctrl).datepicker("option","setDate", new Date(dDate)); //not working
}
```

The above function is called in the cshtml script as below,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var dobDate = $("#Date_Of_Birth").val();
var jtDate = dobDate.split(" ");
OsDatepicker('Date_Of_Birth', 1, 0, jtDate[0]);
});
```

My razor code is as below, for Date of Birth

```
<div style="width: 260px; float: left; height: 45px;">
    <label class="field_title">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date_Of_Birth)</label>
    <div class="form_input">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date_Of_Birth)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date_Of_Birth)
    </div>
</div>
```

The markup of the above is as below,

```
<input class="text-box single-line" id="Date_Of_Birth" name="Date_Of_Birth" type="text" value="13-10-1988 00:00:00" />
```

As you can see the model is fetching the date correctly, which also being passed to the OSDatepicker function correctly.

On loading the form the DateofBirth textbox is blank, unable to crack this. Your suggestions would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the textbox have a value if you disable javascript? This will help us to figure out of the problem lies with Razor or with the JS. Also- which format is Razor outputting the date as?

Comment: If I disable the datepicker for this control, the date appears as in the value i.e, 13-10-1988 00:00:00.

Comment: Put a `console.log(dDate)` just above `$(ctrl).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',`. What do you get?

Comment: I have a feeling this may be because the date razor is outputting is not in the same format as you initialize the picker to be - try setting dateFormat to be 'dd-mm-yyyy' (or update your razor to output the date as dd/MM/yy)

Comment: 02-10-2012... and while debug I see the same value.

Comment: Did you try changing `dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'` to `dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy'`?

Comment: Yup...!! changing to format dd-mm-yy works... thanks for the help paynecrl97.. never though a '/' would make such a difference.

Comment: Glad to help! I've posted this as an answer. Could you accept it? Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because the dateFormat that razor is rendering does not match the format the date picker is expecting.

Have you tried changing `dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'` to `dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy'`?

Comment: .. it is not 'yyyy'.. but 'yy'

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
defaultDate: $("#Date_Of_Birth").val();
```

Comment: I think defaultDate just tells jQueryUI which date should initially be selected when the picker is opened. As I understand it, the problem lies with the textbox not displaying the date (even before the picker has been opened)